# Detect protocol optional url in text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I found a lot of answers to detect url in text. I tried them but failed to detect protocol optional urls. Most of existing solutions could find urls in "Hello, open http://somesite.com/etc to see my photo" and replace the http part to  tags. But they could not work for cases like "Hey, open somesite.com or somesite.com/etc to take a look."

How can I detect both cases (better with one regex), and the default protocol is "http://" for none-protocol urls.

I note that SO also failed to detect the latter case...

Edit:
Maybe it is error-prone to change somesite.com into urls (in English), so this requirement is not ideal?

I used regex /(https?://[^\s]+)/g. This one is simple and support cases like http://abcd.com/etc/?v=3&type=xyz. But I don't know how to change it to support protocol absent case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?\w+\.\w+([\/\w\?\-\+\!\&\$\=\.\:]+)*$
```

Matches:

```
www.domain.com
http://www.domain.com
http://www.somesite.com/etc
http://www.somesite.com/etc/etc/etc
somesite.com
somesite.com/etc

http://google.com/q=regex+for+this&utm-source=stackoverflow
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hS0cQ3)**

Comment: Thanks, it has some effect. Could you allow the url to have some common characters like "?" and "&", so (http://)somesite.com/?id=a&name=b is supported?

Comment: @mrmoment looks like I am late. Nevertheless, I have provided in my effort and edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't bullet proof, but it works with the example you've provided:

```
var text = "Hey, open some-site.com or somesite.com/etc?test=1 to take a look."
var myregexp = /([\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]+\.[a-z]{2,7})(\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|?]+)?/ig;
var result = text.replace(myregexp, '<a href="http://$1$2">$1$2</a>');
alert(result);
```

`//Hey, open <a href="http://some-site.com">some-site.com</a> or <a href="http://somesite.com/etc?test=1">somesite.com/etc?test=1</a> to take a look.`

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/Bf4at/4/)</kbd>

Comment: I add (https?:\/\/)? in the front to comply with the protocol given case. Still, I want to support url with parameters, e.g., some-site.com/?p=3&name=abc. I used /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g. It is simple but not for protocol absent case.

Comment: @mrmoment I've updated the answer to support parameters. If you want to check for the existence of protocol you'll need to match if it exists and then replace accordingly.